# React use input vale to search api

Tags: reactjs

React newbie here... I am pulling my hair out trying to figure this out... I am trying to use bandsintown API to search for bands then display the results. I am having a difficult time taking the entered band name and then using that as part of the fetch to the bansintown API. It appears that things are re-rendering or not rendering in the correct order, etc. I have tried putting my call to fetch in componentDidMount but that renders before the 'band' state is set...please help... here is a snippet of my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class BandSearch extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      band: "",
      events: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleChange();
  }

  async getBand(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await fetch(
        `https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/${
          this.state.band
        }/events?app_id=acdb6da27e696632f85c3733dd43db52`
      );
      const events = await res.json();
      this.setState({
        events: events
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      band: this.result.value
    });
    console.log("state", this.state);
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.band);
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Enter Band to check on tour dates</h3>
        <form>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter band name"
            ref={input => (this.result = input)}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button onClick={this.getBand}>Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BandSearch;
```

Thanks so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the event from the onChange event of the input like so:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    band: e.currentTarget.value
  });
  // console.log("state", this.state); This will have unexpected results. Try to investigate why.
};
```

Also remove the call to handleChange in componentDidMount

Answer (score 0):

You are actually missing this binding your function in your constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getBand = this.getBand.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      band: "",
      events: []
    };
  }
```

Here is the demo of that: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hfkqaw?file=index.js

This is from react

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In
>   JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to
>   bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined
>   when the function is actually called.

full reading here: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: thanks all for the quick responses!...I'll look into this and report back...much appreciated

Comment: I got it working finally... I had to remove the try/ catch clause though but it works great now...Thanks again!

Comment: @g_wizz glad it helped